# javascript check radio button on a <span> element - UX

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have multiple `radio` buttons, each one inside a `<span>` with margin, so they seem like a button with a radio element inside. how can I check the `radio` button when I click anywhere inside the `<span>` parent element of the `radio` button

UX oriented

```
<span class="radio-box" id="white-box">
  <input type="radio" id="white" name="colour"> White
</span>

<span class="radio-box" id="red-box">
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="colour"> Red
</span>

<span class="radio-box"  id="blue-box">
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="colour"> Blue
</span>
```

sorry, very noob at Javascript

thanks :)

Comment: Use a `<label>` instead of a `<span>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **exactly** what [`label` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-label-element) are for. Use those, rather than `span` elements:

```
<label class="radio-box" id="white-box">
  <input type="radio" id="white" name="colour"> White
</label>

<label class="radio-box" id="red-box">
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="colour"> Red
</label>

<label class="radio-box"  id="blue-box">
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="colour"> Blue
</label>
```

When the label wraps the `input` like that, it's associated with that `input`. (If you couldn't use wrapping, you could use the `for` attribute to tell the label what the `id` of its associated `input` is.)

You *could* make it work with spans. Targeting *just* those spans:

```
$("span > input[type=radio][name=colour]").parent().on("click", function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=radio][name=colour]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

or targeting any `input[type=radio]` inside a `span.radio-box`:

```
$("span.radio-box > input[type=radio]").parent().on("click", function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

But again, this is exactly what `label` is for, so best to use that.

Comment: I haven't checked in years but I'm hoping that modern IE/Edge versions do that properly. It used to be that a `for` attribute was required even when the label was wrapped around the input.

Comment: @Pointy - I've been using this wrapping technique at least as far back as IE8, if not IE6. It works just fine.

Comment: OK well I know it was always *supposed* to work. My memories of IE6 workarounds are hazy at best and it's always hard to tease apart things that really didn't work from things that I erroneously concluded didn't work. Heck it may be Netscape 4 I'm thinking of!

Comment: @Pointy - You're right, it doesn't work in IE6. (I had an old VM lying around. :-) ) Does in IE8, and I suspect it did in IE7, but... (That actually makes me feel better about some really old code I wrote and ran across a while back that did it manually. That code was part of a project that had to support IE6. I was kind of vaguely beating myself up about it... Thanks! :-) )

Comment: that was pretty easy, yes i use span to frequenly! thanks will note that :)

found this in the html documentation: "On other platforms, the behavior might be just to focus the control, or do nothing."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without the `<label>` tag and without jquery and just vanilla JavaScript then here's a solution.

```
var radioBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("span.radio-box");
radioBoxes.forEach(function (box) {
    var radioButton = box.querySelector("input[type='radio']");
    box.addEventListener("click", function () {
        radioButton.click();
    });
});
```